# Find the hydrostatic force using integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

A vertical dam has a semicircular gate. Find the hydrostatic force against the gate.

The dam is 12 meters high, the water level is at 10 meters, and the semicircular gate had a diameter of 4 meters.

The formula for the force on the dam is:
$$\int_0^apgW(y)(a-y)dy$$

where a would  be the water level, y=0 would refer to the bottom of the dam, W(y) is the width of the dam (a.k.a the length of the dam) and the x-axis goes along the bottom of the gate.

Since this isn't a dam but a semicircular gate of the dam, I am not sure how to proceed. I know $W(y)=2\sqrt{4-y^2}$ and $a=2$.

Am I approaching this problem correctly?

Comment: Does your formula for $W(y)$ imply that the gate is at the bottom of the dam? That information is missing in the problem statement.

Comment: @joriki yeah, it is at the bottom...sorry for not adding that..

Comment: I assume $p$ is the mass density of water and $g$ the acceleration of Gravity. The parameter $b$ doesn't seem to belong in the formula, I think it should be $(a-y)$ in the integrand instead of $(b-y)$

Comment: @WW1 oh yeah, let me edit it

Comment: Completely correct. Now just substitute that value into the integral and find its value. You're probably going to need to use substitution to solve the integral though.